# For Loop Without Init,Condition, Increment

Tags: c

Hey guys i stumble upon a code online which was written in C language and while reading the codes i saw the `for` loop did not have `initialization`,`condition` nor the `increment`. The loop looked like this.

```
for (;;)
{
    bool main_flag = false;
    while (main_flag == false)
    {
        displayMainMenu();
        switch (main_input)
        {
        case 1: addCar(head, tail); main_flag = true; break;
        case 2: removeCar(head, tail); main_flag = true; break;
        case 3: display(head, tail); main_flag = true; break;
        case 4: printf("Terminating..."); return 0;
        default: printf("\nINVALID INPUT!\nTRYAGAIN !\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Anyone able to explain to me what kind of `for` loop is that and how does it work? thanks alot

Comment: no magic here, You just need to have a break/return inside the loop for a condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly doing what it implies: There is no condition to stop the loop, hence it is actually an endless loop.

So

```
for(;;) {}
```

is essentially the same as

```
while(true) {}
```

The only way to get out of the loop is to use a `break` or a `return`.

Comment: or `exit`͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Bathsheba -- or segfault ;)

Comment: @DavidBowling: Strictly that's a manifestation of UB. Not sure we can really count that one.

Comment: hmm now that u mentioned does make sense... alright thanks

Comment: And the reason you may see `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)` is that the former is, when viewed from a certain perspective, more efficient than the latter, because the former just loops while technically the latter must check the truth value each iteration to determine whether to keep looping.  But practically speaking the compiler will almost certainly treat them exactly the same.